# Alert(Modal Window) Box On Statement

Tags: php, javascript, html

How would I go about making a Alert Box popup when a statement written in PHP comes into play?

The JS code that I have going right now to make this work is this:

```
$(".bAlert").click( function() {
    jAlert('This is a custom alert box. Title and this text can be easily editted', 'Alert Dialog Sample');
});
```

This code works fine when using it for a button, but I want it to show up when this statement comes into play:

```
if ($operation == "divide") { 
    $answer = $number1 / $number2;
    $operation = "&#247;";
} else {
    $output = "CODE TO MAKE THIS WORK HAS TO GO HERE"; 
}
```

This is how it works using a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Usual alert" class="basicBtn mr10 ml10 bAlert" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in the else statement

```
if ($operation == "divide"):
    $answer = $number1 / $number2;
    $operation = "&#247;";
 else:
    echo "<script>jAlert('This is a custom alert box. Title and this text can be easily editted', 'Alert Dialog Sample');</script>"; 
    endif;
```

Comment: Unless that php is already located within some script tags, you'll probably need to wrap it in script tags too right?

Comment: I don't think the `.click()` handler is needed, at least my impression is the OP just wants to call `jAlert()` directly.